# Not closing cursor or database object?

Tags: java, android

I get this error after going to this activity, starting a new one, coming back. It doesn't happen when I first load the activity. functionally everything works... but I still get this error.

> ERROR/Cursor(1059): Finalizing a
>   Cursor that has not been deactivated
>   or closed. database =
>   /data/data/com.roger.testapp/databases/data,
>   table = null, query = SELECT MAX(_id)
>   FROM record
>
> 03-02 16:47:21.835:
>   ERROR/Cursor(1059):
>   android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException:
>   Application did not close the cursor
>   or database object that was opened
>   here

In onCreate:

```
    mDbHelper = new CommonDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    fillData();
```

fillData() calls fetchNote in my dbhelper, the cursor is used for a couple things, if rowId == 0, that means I didn't select an item to get into this activity and I want to get the last row in that table. if rowId = something else, then I grab that row. I think the problem is in here somewhere, I'm just not sure.

```
public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId, String table, String columns) throws SQLException {
    if (rowId == 0) {
        String query = "SELECT MAX(_id) FROM record";
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
        rowId = 0;     
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {               
          rowId = cursor.getInt(0);                         
        }
    }
    Cursor mCursor =
        mDb.query(true, table, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                columns}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}
```

In onDestroy:

```
super.onDestroy();
    if (mDbHelper != null) {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
```

Also, I am startManagingCursor

Comment: Is `super.onDestroy()` actually getting called?

Comment: I don't see anything about destroy in the log. It's just something I tried... seems like the error happens less with it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't close your database in `onDestroy`.  Close it immediately after you're done using it(make sure every cursor is closed before the database is closed).  onDestroy may not be called when you expect.

Also, close your `Cursor` object after you're done using it.

Edits:
Since your activity is managing your `Cursor`, you may consider stop managing it and closing everything in the `onPause` method, and in `onResume` open everything up and `fillData` once again.  If you could change your code around so you dont rely on your activity managing the cursor, you wouldn't need to hold into open database objects and worry about them.

Comment: I've been trying that. I don't think I have the location right though. At the end of private void fillData() (gathers info to send to fetchNote), put mDbHelper.close();
  c.close();?

Comment: When I'm in the activity, I can click an item that calls another activity, then hit the back button. After I do this 5 times, it's then that I get the error. Does that provide any more info on what it might be? If I have the activity stop managing the cursor, I get the errors all the time.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend not returning a cursor.  It's a scarce resource.

In n-tiered Java EE, the best practice is to close all persistence resources (Connection, Statement and ResultSet) in the scope of the method in which they were created.  Map a ResultSet into an object or collection and close the ResultSet.

I don't know if there's something special about Android that would invalidate this.

Comment: In android, you can fill a `ListView` automatically by providing it with a `Cursor`. The `ListActivity` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) does this for example, as does the [Notepad Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html). If you want to use this and still wrap your database code into a table class (like in notepad tutorial), you need to return a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) - you can see that when you navigate away from your activity (`onPause`) if another activity needs memory your process is killed, but when your user then returns to the activity, it will hit `onCreate` again. This time you are opening a NEW CommonDbAdapter (but you never closed the original one) - thus when you eventually hit `onDestroy` you would only close the very latest mDbHelper.

As stated by others, your best method is not to pass the cursor back from the DBHelper, create an object with your data, close the cursor and pass your object back. Also close the DBHelper once you have used it, you can always create another if you need to use it again.

Comment: I moved the new CommonDbAdapter to inside fillData(), and I close the db and cursor before the end of fillData(). I'm still seeing the error though. But when I navigate from that activity and come back, I don't get an error... but if I navigate away, come back, navigate away, come back 5 times, then I get the error. So maybe it's running out of memory and then after 5 times putting me back into onCreate?

Comment: It is quite possible after creating 5 new activities it is then running out of space - try adding the `mDbHelper.close()` to the end of your `fillData()` to make sure you have finished with the DB. After all you are now creating a new CommonDbAdapter when the function starts. Also take a look at [startManagingCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startManagingCursor(android.database.Cursor))

Comment: Also you should close your cursor when you have finished with it in `fillData()` as well. After all it the cursor being left open which is throwing the error for you - not necessarily the database being open!